# How to appropriately set spindown (Power Management) when using SnapRaid?

Tags: debian, power-management, union-mount

I run `openmediavault 4.1` and changed from `RAID6` to `SnapRaid` with 7 hard drives for data plus parity.

I remember reading installation advice on RAID setup that said "never set spindown for HDD" while using `autoshutdown`. So I was running fine for some years having the whole system shut down after 30 minutes of beeing idle - instead of having the disks beeing spun down and leaving the rest on power consumption.

Now I changed my setup to `SnapRaid` with `mergerfs` and I wonder if I have to reset my spindown settings in Power Management. Access on a `RAID` array spins up all of the disks at once. With `SnapRaid` only the one disk with the actual data on it will be activated. So it would make sense to put all of them to spindown because most of them will not be used anyway.

I decided so put it on "minimum consumption WITH spindown" and set spindown to 10 minutes. The whole system shuts down after 60 minutes of beeing ide.

I think this is better because `SnapRaid` will spin up only the one disk it needs if there is some access.

Is this a good setup?